# Why won't some unicode characters print to my terminal?

Tags: bash, fonts, unicode, printf

I'm running Arch Linux with simple terminal using the Adobe Source Code Pro font. My locale is correctly set to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

I want to print Unicode characters representing playing cards to my terminal. I'm using [Wikipedia for reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode).

The Unicode characters for card suits work fine. For example, issuing

```
$ printf "\u2660"
```

prints a black heart to the screen.

However, I'm having trouble with specific playing cards. Issuing

```
$ printf "\u1F0A1"
```

prints the symbol `Ἂ1` instead of the ace of spades . What's going wrong?

This problem persists across several terminals (urxvt, xterm, termite) and every font I've tried (DejaVu, Inconsolata).

Comment: Warning: if this is handled by printf, it is a non-standard enhancement. So do not expect such escapes to work at all. See: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`help printf` defers to `printf(1)` for the escape sequences interpreted, and [the docs for GNU printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#index-_005cuhhhh) says:

> `printf` interprets two character syntaxes introduced in ISO C 99:
>   `\u` for 16-bit Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) characters, specified as four
>   hexadecimal digits *hhhh*, and `\U` for 32-bit Unicode characters,
>   specified as eight hexadecimal digits *hhhhhhhh*. `printf` outputs the
>   Unicode characters according to the `LC_CTYPE` locale. Unicode
>   characters in the ranges U+0000…U+009F, U+D800…U+DFFF cannot be
>   specified by this syntax, except for U+0024 ($), U+0040 (@), and
>   U+0060 (`).

Something similar is specified in the Bash manual for [ANSI C Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-quoting_002c-ANSI) and [`echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-echo):

> `\uHHHH`
>   the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal
>   value *HHHH* (one to four hex digits)
>
> `\UHHHHHHHH`
>   the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal
>   value *HHHHHHHH* (one to eight hex digits)

In short: `\u` is not for 5 hex digits. It's `\U`:

```
# printf "\u2660 \u1F0A1 \U1F0A1\n"
♠ Ἂ1
```

Answer (score 2):

Muru's answer is completely correct, but just to clarify one point:

When you're printing `\u1F0A1`, that's interpreted as a sixteen-bit Unicode escape `\u1F0A`, followed by the literal character `1` (since `\u` takes the following *four* characters, no more, no less). U+1F0A then gives `Ἂ`, a Greek alpha with a couple diacritics on it (*Greek Capital Letter Alpha with Psili and Varia*, to be precise).

If you want more than sixteen bits in your Unicode escape, you need to use `\U`, which takes eight characters' worth of hex: `\U0001F0A1` will give you the playing card.

Comment: `\U0001F0A1` is actually more portable than `\U1F0A1`. It's the GNU standalone `printf` utility which first introduced those `\uXXXX`/`\UXXXXXXXX` sequences and it does require 4 digits for `\u` and 8 for `\U`.  Other `printf` implementations like the builtin of the GNU shell, ksh93 and zsh are more lax. In any case `printf '\u/\U'` is not POSIX. POSIX is however going to specify zsh's `$'\U1F0A1'` and will not require all 8 digits.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Interesting, I'd always figured that POSIX would go with the eight-digit one. I assume the eight-digit version is still valid in zsh if you want to avoid capturing extra letters and numbers after the code?

Comment: Yes, `\uxxxx` is *up* to 4 digits and `\Uxxxxxxxx` is *up* to 8 digits. Note that Unicode is now limited to codepoints 0 to 0x10FFFF (a limitation brought by UTF16) so code points will never have more than 6 digits (still `\U123456789` would be interpreted as the character of code point 0x12345678 followed by `9` and fail). The POSIX specification for `$'\u\U'` is still not finalised (see http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=249). In an earlier draft, they required all 4/8 digits but that changed later (upon my request).